# _.each Unexpected token if error while templating

Tags: underscore.js-templating

I am using underscore.js to put my EJS values to template.
I am getting unexpected token if error 
When i click on the error i am getting x.for and for each ananymous function.this is code below

```
enter code here
 var a; is and array of objects. 
_.each(a,function(b){
```

var tem=_.template('$('#id1').html());
   $('.c').append(tem(p:b));}

any idea what's going wrong?